# Font style for e-mail body in VBA

Tags: html, vba, excel

I have the following code written in VBA:

```
 Dim StrBody As String

 StrBody = "Text Line 1" & "<br>" & _
           "Text Line 2" & _
```

How do I change the font to get a particular style (e.g. Arial), size, and color?

The text is used as the body of an e-mail. That's why some better looking style needs to be used. The default font is "Times New Roman".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine you would have to use the `font` tag and its various attributes:

```
StrBody = "<font size=""10"" face=""Arial"" color=""red"">" & _
          "Text Line 1" & "<br>" & _
          "Text Line 2" & _ 
          "</font>"
```

Make sure the `"` quotes used to surround HTML attribute values don't get interpreted as the end of the VBA string: escape them by writing `""` instead, as in the example above.

`color` can also be specified as hexadecimal RGB codes. So `color="red"` could be replaced by the more general `color="#FF0000"`.