# How can I change the font style of a string?

Tags: c#, html

I have a string that I am sending to an e-mail Server to be the body of an e-mail.  I'm trying to control what font it will end up in the e-mail. Here is the string:

```
@"Dear " + txtName.Text + ",<br/><br/>Thank you for submitting. <br/><br/>In the event of any changes, please submit again here" + link + ". <br><br>The following is a summary for your records.<br/><br/>"
```

How would I make the font, say, Times New Roman?

It seems that all the information out there about font changing always involves using an ASP control but that's out of the picture in this case.

Comment: Can you assume it will be read in HTML? If so, just surround the text with a span and add style to it. Also, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090295/font-style-for-e-mail-body?rq=1

Comment: It will be read via Outlook. And as we know Outlook has primitive HTML rendering for safety reasons.  I can't assume the user will jump through hoops to enable anything extra.

Comment: @user1327418 Outlook reads HTML and CSS. But you cant link an extra file. You have to write your css into your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

To change the [font-family](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), you must use **CSS**.

```
string mail = @"Dear " + txtName.Text + ",<br/><br/>Thank you for submitting. <br/><br/>In the event of any changes, please submit again here" + link + ". <br><br>The following is a summary for your records.<br/><br/>"
```

for example with `Time New Roman`:

```
mail = "<p><span style=\"font-family: Time New Roman;\">" + mail + </span></p>"
```

You should know that you can use different font, if the client did not have the first one :

```
font-family: Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;
```

If you want more tips about mail formatting :

- [Using CSS in HTML Emails: The Real Story](http://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/) by Chris Coyier
- [How to Create Great HTML Emails with CSS](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/article.php/3679231) by Christian MacAuley

Comment: Actually, you *can* alternatively use `<font face="Times New Roman">...</font>`. People just recommend CSS as a matter of principle. And if you use CSS, you don’t need that extra `span` element; you can set `style` on the `p` element.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela For `<font>`: of course you can, but that is not mean that you should. For styling the `<span>` instead of `<p>` : you got a point. I just want to show OP, that He can add any HTML tag in his code. Maybe I should not or I  was not clear. Well I hope your comment can be useful too. Kudo for you.