# Change the color of a single word in an Email.htmlbody

Tags: excel, vba

i am new to Excel VBA programming. I am writing a macro to automatically send emails from Excel.
I would like to know how to change the color of a specific word in the Email.htlmbody.
I can 'bold' a word but don't know how to change color.
Example:

```
Email.htmlbody = "<p>Hello my <b>friend</b>!</p>" & _
                 "<p>Please send the report by July, 30th</p>"
```

How can I make 'July, 30th' in red?

Comment: It's just HTML that you include in your string, just like you did with the other HTML tags. There are tons of different ways to do it. http://www.simplehtmlguide.com/cheatsheet.php

Comment: Duplicate of [Font style for e-mail body in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21090295/font-style-for-e-mail-body-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HTML tags:

```
<p>Hello my <b>friend!</b></p>
<p>Please send the report by <span style="color:red">July, 30th</span></p>
```

Of course the above in VBA is just a string so it should be wrapped in `"` quotes.